# How to set defaultValue parameter in @DataField Camel annotation to empty String instead of null?

Tags: java, csv, apache-camel, bindy

I try to unmarshall csv file using apache camel and bindy. I created a model with some fields annotated like this:

```
@DataField(pos = 5, defaultValue = "")
```

The problem is when my csv file contains a column with empty String. Then I got a null value as a result of unmarshalling. I would like to have empty String there as well. How should I write my annotation to get this?

Answer (score 2):

Version (2.18.0) appears to have support.

While converting the string-token (from the CSV file) to the field which was annotated by @DataField, the steps are as follow:

1. If trim=true, trim the string-token
2. If required and string-token is "", throw Exception
3. Get the appropriate converter, based on the type of the field
4. If string-token was NOT "" use the converter on the string-token
5. else if a default-string was specified, use the converter on the default
6. else if a java primitive (e.g. int) return an appropriate value (MIN)
7. else return null

Version 2.18.0 introduces a new annotation @BindyConverter, allowing you to specify any class that adheres to the Format interface (effectively intercepting step #3, above)

A custom converter will allow you to read the default value and convert it according to your own requirements (in step #5 above). Your converter will also need to handle step #4, but this is trivial for Strings.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I am using Camel 2.17.0 and my test ends with error anyway: org.junit.ComparisonFailure: expected:<[]> but was:<[ ]>. It looks like trim does not work for me after reading the value. Any idea why?

Comment: Sorry, maybe I made a mistake here. I did run some code to test this before I answered yesterday, but cannot reproduce it now. Maybe it was something else I did when I was playing around with this. I will try again and either edit or delete my answer... depending on what I find.

Comment: Is it bad because i exactly need null when the string is empty and don't have anyway to do that

Answer (score 2):

I followed the comment by @Darius X. and here is what worked for me:

```
@Column
@DataField(pos = 1, defaultValue = "default")
@BindyConverter(CustomConverter.class)
private String someField= "";

public static class CustomConverter implements Format<String> {
    @Override
    public String format(String object) {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public String parse(String string) {
        return "";
    }
}
```